# In C# trying to split a comma delimited list into an object

Tags: c#

I haven't seen any examples like this, so hopefully this isn't a duplicate.   I have a process that's given this string:

```
Line1=LineOne;Line2=LineTwo;City=City;State=StateOrProvidence;Zip=PostalCode
```

I need to turn this into an AddressField object:

```
public class AddressField 
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not finding a simple way to do this.  Trying to split it into a dictionary or list, but nothing is working as easily as I hoped.  Also it has to be in DotNet Framework 4.6.2 without any extra add-ins.
Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: "Trying to split it into a dictionary or list" - show your code.

Comment: I didn't think showing the code would be necessary as it didn't even come close to doing what I needed.  I'll pull it back out and share -- just throwing stuff on the wall to see what sticks, and thus far nothing is.

Comment: split on `;`, then iterate and create your object.  If the order of properties is always the same, just split each substring on `=` and assign.  If its not always the same, you could potentially use reflection

Comment: `haven't seen any examples like this` - but there must be plenty examples of the two separate steps that you appear to be in need of. The first is "read CSV C#", the second is "split key value pairs C#".

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Just for fun: `STR.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split('=')).Aggregate(new AddressField(), (obj, kv) => { typeof(AddressField).GetProperty(kv[0]).SetValue(obj, kv[1]); return obj; })`

Comment: A major part of programming is learning how to solve problems independently. When you have a big problem that you don't know how to solve, start by breaking it down into smaller problems and solving those smaller problems. In your example, your first problem is "How do I split this on a semicolon?" then your next problem is "How do I separate the field name from the data?" then the final problem is "How do I assign the value to the appropriate field in an instance of `AddressField`?"

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to create a static method on the class that returns an instance of the class based on an input string. You could split the string on the semi-colon character, and then split each result on the equals sign, ending up with the key-value pairs for each property. Then you could use a switch statement to parse the pairs and set the appropriate property values:

```
public class AddressField
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public static AddressField FromString(string input)
    {
        if (input == null) return null;

        AddressField result = new AddressField();

        foreach(var kvp in input.Split(';'))
        {
            var parts = kvp.Split('=');
            if (parts.Length == 2)
            {
                switch(parts[0])
                {
                    case "Line1":
                        result.Line1 = parts[1];
                        break;
                    case "Line2":
                        result.Line2 = parts[1];
                        break;
                    case "City":
                        result.City = parts[1];
                        break;
                    case "State":
                        result.State = parts[1];
                        break;
                    case "Zip":
                        result.Zip = parts[1];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var addressField = AddressField.FromString("Line1=LineOne;Line2=LineTwo;City=City;State=StateOrProvidence;Zip=PostalCode");
```

Answer (score 0):

### The simple solution

Create a `Parse()` function to manually assign values

```
public class AddressField
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Line1={Line1};Line2={Line2};City={Line1};State={State};Zip={Zip}";
    }

    public static AddressField Parse(string line)
    {
        AddressField result = new AddressField();
        string[] parts = line.Split(';');
        foreach (var item in parts)
        {
            string[] values = item.Split('=');

            switch (values[0])
            {
                case "Line1":
                    result.Line1 = values[1];
                    break;
                case "Line2":
                    result.Line2 = values[1];
                    break;
                case "City":
                    result.City = values[1];
                    break;
                case "State":
                    result.State = values[1];
                    break;
                case "Zip":
                    result.Zip = values[1];
                    break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and test it with

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "Line1=LineOne;Line2=LineTwo;City=City;State=StateOrProvidence;Zip=PostalCode";
    AddressField address = AddressField.Parse(input);
    Console.WriteLine(address);
}
```

Of course, a lot of checks are missing here to create robust code. The above is just for illustrative purposes.

### The Dynamic Solution

You can use a `ExpandObject` to build a type on the go as you parse values, and then convert into a `AddressField`.

```
public class AddressField
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Line1={Line1};Line2={Line2};City={Line1};State={State};Zip={Zip}";
    }

    public static AddressField Parse(string line)
    {
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        IDictionary<string, object> properties = obj;

        string[] parts = line.Split(';');
        foreach (var item in parts)
        {
            string[] values = item.Split('=');
            properties[values[0]] = values[1];
        }

        return new AddressField()
        {
            Line1 = obj.Line1,
            Line2 = obj.Line2,
            City = obj.City,
            State = obj.State,
            Zip = obj.Zip,
        };
    }
}
```